# write a loop that prints a number of lines the user entered into the text box, this is using c# windows application

Tags: c#, arrays, windows

write a loop that prints a number of lines the user entered into the text box
for example, this is using c# windows application

user inputs 10, then in another textbox counts from 0 to 10 on different lines

Result 
0 \r\n
1 \r\n
2 \r\n
3 \r\n
4 \r\n
5 \r\n
6 \r\n
7  \r\n
8 \r\n
9 \r\n
10 \r\n

i have tried to incorporate a for loop and for each but it is only printing out one value, and i have to go into the array and print each iteration of the array like so textboxOutput.text = Array[0] + Array[1] , but i want it to print out all of the list without accessing the single ints in the array

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = textBox1.Text;
        int Number;


        bool Anumber = Int32.TryParse(input, out Number);
        int newNumber = Number;
        int[] List = new int[newNumber];

            for (int i = 0; i < List.Length; i++ )
            {

                List[i] = i;
                //textBox2.Text =List[0] + "\r\n" + List[1] + "\r\n" + List[2];
            }
            foreach (int num in List)
            {
                textBox2.Text = num.ToString() ;
            }
}  
}
```

}

Comment: post the code with which you're having issues

Comment: I believe the problem is that if you're single-threading this application, all the code will execute at once, the end result being it will only show the final value set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure out my own question

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int OutputNumber;  
        bool number = Int32.TryParse(inputtxt.Text, out OutputNumber);
        string[] array = new string[OutputNumber];
        int put = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {

            array[i] = put.ToString();
            put++;

            string result = ConvertStringArrayToString(array);
            string result1 = result + OutputNumber.ToString();
            outputtxt.Text = result1;
        }}

            static string ConvertStringArrayToString(string[] array)
        {

            StringBuilder buildingstring = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string value in array)
            {
                buildingstring.Append(value);
                buildingstring.Append("\r\n");
            }
            return buildingstring.ToString();
}
```

I have gone around a different way, by creating a string array adding each value to the string array and using a separate function to join all of the string array data together and separating each value with a return

Comment: alternatively you can just keep adding onto the string by concatenating them repeatedly, like `aString = aString + newValue + "\r\n";`